# Vue js3: How to add router link & icons in aray items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have an array of nav items including subnav I have added to a sidebar component in a dashboard I am making.
I will like to add router links with different icons to each item in the array. I am still trying to wrap my head around how to do it and I really need help.
below is the code sample.

**Array nav items**

```
state: {

navigation: [
  
  {title: "Home"},
  
  {
    title: "Posts",
    poen: true,
    subnav:[
      {title: "Published"},
      {title: "Draft"},
      {title: "Trashed"},
    ]
  },

  {
    title: "Users",
    open: true,
    subnav:[
      {title: "Admins"},
      {title: "Authors"},
      {title: "Editors"},
      {title: "Subscribers"}
    ]
  },

]
},
getters: {

navigation: state => {
  return state.navigation
}



 },
```

**Sidebar menu items**

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li v-for="(item, index) in navigation" :key="'item'+index">

    <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open">{{item.title}}</div>

    <Dropdown v-if="item.subnav" :list="item" />
</li>
```

**Drop Down Items**

```
<ul v-show="list.open">
<li v-for="(item, index) in list.subnav" :key="'item' +index">

    <div class="title" @click="item.open = !item.open">{{item.title}}</div>

    <Dropdown v-if="item.subnav" :list="item" />
</li>
```

So that in the end, I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways (or more)

1st, you can import and add the icon class to the array of objects to later bind it to the template.

Eg. [heroicons](https://vue-hero-icons.netlify.app/) and usage.

```
import { UserCircleIcon, ..otherIconsImaginary } from "@heroicons/vue/solid";


navigation: [ 
  {title: "Home", icon: UserCircleIcon},
  {title: "Posts",poen: true,icon: PostsIcon,
  subnav:[
    {title: "Published", icon: SomeOtherIcon},
    {title: "Draft", icon: DraftsIcon},
    {title: "Trashed", icon: TrashedIcon},
    ]
   }
  ]
```

Then on your template bind it as a component

2nd, Import your icons from anywhere and then define icon classes for all objects.

```
navigation: [
     { title: "Home", icon_class: "home-icon" }...
]
```

then bind it as an image like this

```
<img :src="homeIcon" alt="" v-if="item.icon_class === 'home-icon'" />
```

PS. I think you should use the state for user information management only. This code can be finished in layouts since you can have multiple layouts for authenticated, non-authenticated, 404, and other pages as per your business logic wideness.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the assistance. But importing icons like this: import { ChevronDownIcon } from "@vue-hero-icons/solid"
keeps on returning an error and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: have you installed it? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heroicons/vue

Comment: Yes it has been installed

Comment: I just want to thank you for this snippet.  Option 1 worked great and all that is needed is ` <component :is="route.icon">` for the router loop (i.e. route.path, route.name, etc.)